# Arangodb nested attribute sorting spring data

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data, arangodb, arangodb-java

I have my arango sample record as shown below

```
{
   "id" : "CNHFDGSH5K",
   "outerstring" : "XTRAVIL"
   "properties" : {
     "name": "ACASE23"
    }
}
```

Want to Sort by `properties.name` in Pagination

```
PageRequest.of(
                pagenum - 1,
                pageSize,
                Sort.by(ASC, String.format("%s.%s", "collectionName", "properties.name")));
```

Sorting works for if I pass "outerstring" but it does not work with `"properties.name"`

using `arangodb-spring-data` library version 3.5.1 / spring.data commons 2.7.16 and ArangoRepository